# How to implement "Drag and Drop" functionality in django-mptt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-mptt

I use [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) application in my project. This application allows users drag and drop tree nodes in admin page (`DraggableMPTTAdmin`). Is it possible to make the same functionality in custom template (not in admin)?

**P.S.** I tried to use `jsTree` plugin in frontend. This plugin allows the user drag and drop nodes of the tree but jsTree has heavy API. Also I dont know how to save new structure of new tree cause jsTree render strange attributes in html for tree nodes.

**template:**

```
<ul class="root">
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            {{ node.name }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```